# Java REGEX With Document Filter

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtextfield

I have been trying to figure out a REGEX expressions which can filter characters which are not '-' or 0-9. This expression will be used with a document filter which will filter characters being inserted into JTextFields. Let me explain in more detail...

When a user enters a character into a JTextField a DocumentFilter checks the input using the `replace` method in the DocumentFilter class. Because the method is called every time a character is inserted the REGEX needed to be able to handle parts of an integer as the user builds the string. For example,

```
Key Press 1): Value = '-' PASS
Key Press 2): Value = '-1' PASS
Key Press 3): Value = '-10' PASS etc...
```

However the filter should not allow the combination '-0' or '--' and should pass the following cases,

Negative Symbol Only ('-')

Negative Number Without Zero Next To '-' ('-01' fail)

Positive Values (0122 and 122 pass)

Here is my code:

```
package regex;

import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class CustomFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    private String regex = "((-?)([1-9]??))(\d)";

    /**
     * Called every time a new character is added.
     */
    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        String text = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
        text += string;

        if(text.matches(regex)) {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user pastes in new text.
     */
    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

        String string = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
        string += text;

        if(string.matches(regex)) {
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
        super.remove(fb, offset, length); // I may modify this later
    }
}
```

If you believe I am going about this in the wrong direction please let me know. I am open to a more simplistic option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of all the alternations, factor it down to this

`"^(?=[-\\d])(?:-(?!0))?\\d*$"`

Explained

```
 ^                             # Beginning of string
 (?= [-\d] )                   # Must be a character in it
 (?:                           # Optional minus sign
      -
      (?! 0 )                       # If not followed by 0
 )?
 \d*                           # Optional digits [0-9]
 $                             # End of string
```

***Mod:***

With a little extra effort, you could get the partial valid string in
capture group 1 and any remaining *invalid trailing chars* in group 2.

All this requires is to test if there is a match.
Of course you need the matcher to get the groups.

Possible outcomes:

1. The regex didn't match, the string is empty.
   Action: take no action.
2. Regex matched.
   **a**. Action: If length of group 2 > 0, write to text field
   with group 1 string, and place cursor at the end.
   **b**. Action: If length of group 2 == 0, take no action, input is going correctly.

`"^(?=.)((?:-(?>(?=0)|\\d*)|\\d*))(.*)$"`

https://regex101.com/r/oxmZfa/1

Explained

```
 ^                             # Beginning of string

 (?= . )                       # Must be a character in the string

 (                             # (1 start), Template for pattial validity
      (?:
           -                             # The case for minus
           (?>                           # Atomic group for safety
                (?= 0 )                       # Don't capture 0 if it's ahead
             |                              # or,
                \d*                           # Any digits, 0 won't be first
           )
        |                              # or, the case for No minus
           \d*                           # Any digits
      )
 )                             # (1 end)

 ( .* )                        # (2), This is to be trimmed, stuff here doesn't match the template

 $                             # End of string
```

When the user submits the text use this regex to validate the input.
If it doesn't match, the user did not add numbers to the field.
Just popup a message that the input is incomplete.

`"^(?=[-\\d])(?:-(?!0))?\\d+$"`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out right after posting this question! (funny how things work out)

Regex Expression: `^(-{1})|(-[1-9])|(-[1-9]([0-9]{1,}))|([0-9]{1,})$`

For anyone who didn't know (like I) `|` is an OR symbol in regex. So this expression will allow values to pass by matching the string in steps,

`(-{1})` Passes one '-'

`(-[1-9])` Passes a '-' which one non zero integer is appended to

`(-[1-9]([0-9]{1,}))` Passes a '-' with one non zero integer appended to and also allows any number of integers after this pass

`([0-9]{1,})` Passes any positive integer regardless of the starting integer

Hope this helps!